# How to make this effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

as you can see in the photo example. I would like to know how can we create **smooth gradient** like that.Thank in advance

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu05l.jpg[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried, or what has failed?

Comment: Hi, i only know to do the normal gradient effect and what have acrossed my mine was using gradient in certain area with any sort of selection tool. However, if so i wouldn't be able to achieve that smooth transition between different selected area tho.

Comment: Try creating each piece of hill/mountain on its own layer, engage the transparent pixel lock on each layer, use a large soft edged brush with low opacity to paint the variations

Comment: i tried but still couldn't make that soft transition between edges... Would be much beholden to see real example and actual tutorial steps

Comment: [here](https://imgur.com/a/3njhs3B) this is what i could achieve

Comment: i guess it does at certain degree and definitely informative to experience further. Thank for relating the question

Comment: I just noticed that this question in fact seems to be about the same effect as your newest one. Since the new one seems a little easier to understand and got an answer, I chose to vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks that will do